# Send POST HTTP with ClaudiaJS and AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, facebook, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I building a service for push notifications in the facebook messenger. My nodejs app works fine in my localhost, but doesn't in AWS.

I use request module (npm) for send message.

My service can get the parameters, but doesn't send HTTP POST.

```
var ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder'),
  api = new ApiBuilder();

var request = require('request')



api.get('hello', function (req) {

  var token = req.queryString.token;
  var sender = req.queryString.sender;
  var msg = req.queryString.msg;
  messageData = {};
  messageData.text = msg;

  request({
      url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
      qs: { access_token: token },
      method: 'POST',
      json: {
          recipient: { id: sender },
          message: messageData,
      }
  }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
          return 'Error sending message: ' + error;
      } else if (response.body.error) {
          return 'Error: ' + response.body.error;
      }
  });



  return sender + ' ' + messageData.text  ;
})


module.exports = api;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a promise out of the API builder method handler for asynchronous operations. You can use something like `got` or `minimal-request-promise` to turn the HTTP request into a Promise, or just use a simple promise wrapper such as `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => request(...., function (error, result) { if (error) { return reject(errror); else resolve(result) } }))`

See item #4 in the guide on how to use external services from Claudia here: https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/external-services.html

Comment: Using just the promise wrapper worked great! Thanks!